# Piwik: Track own access to the site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, matomo

Piwik is currently installed on the same server as the website that I'm tracking. Now for all the users on the wordpress site on an external ip address, tracking is not a problem because I can see it in the visitor's log. However, I want to track my own access to the site when I access but it doesn't seem to register me as a visitor.

I've looked into this link which tracks unique visitors with the same IP:

http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_175/

But I've realized that this still does not help me in this issue because I still need to access it from my own server. Is there any way that Piwik can let me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check user settings. Maybe you excluded your own visits (Exclude your visits using a cookie option).

Comment: I did look into user settings. I don't think I've excluded my visits because I see this message on the settings "Your visits are not ignored by Piwik (the Piwik ignore cookie was not found in your browser)."

Comment: So maybe you are using a browser plugin that is blocking tracking request (e.g. ghostery or adblock with custom rules)? Please check browser's console (network tab) and confirm, that there is a request to piwik.php

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions and verified that there is a request to piwik.php and I also see that piwik.js is also included. Also, I've checked on Chrome to see if there were any plugins that could block this, tested accessing the site using other browsers, and had the other developers try to access it on their own workstations but still had no luck.

Comment: @AlexisKarloMaglonso then maybe it's a firewall at your company that might block this?

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. I've also consulted our network administrator guy. He stated that we are currently on a flat network, and that there is no firewall on the domain network that prevents the application from doing what it should do. Also, the Private network and Public network firewalls were already off when piwik was being tested and it still wasn't able to do any tracking.